# SUM and VLOOKUP combination

Tags: excel, sum, lookup

I have a table like this:

```
Year  V1 V2 V3
2022  1% 2% 3%
2023  3% 1% 2%
2024  4% 3% 1%
2025  1% 4% 2%
```

I want to look up and sum percentages for values based on start and end years (so an outcome would look like this):

```
Value StartYear EndYear CumulativePercentage
V1    2022      2025    9%
V2    2023      2024    4%
V3    2022      2023    5%
```

Is it possible to create a single formula that would do this?

Comment: Have you tried `SUMIFS` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the answer for V1:

```
 =SUMIFS(B2:B5;A2:A5;">="&B10;A2:A5;"<="&C10)
```

Comment: With a note to OP: depending on your settings, the formula separator may be `,` instead of `;`.